# I think I'm the target of a rude joke in chat

Tags: discussion, etiquette, chat

Today, in our [In praise of Math.SE site and its users](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/17403/in-praise-of-math-se-site-and-its-users) chatroom I saw the following [message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19131473#19131473):

> [in Mathematics, 2 hours ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19129449#19129449), by Behaviour
>
> > Just stopping by to say [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current) is awesome. Great to have folks like this around.

I know I give a poor contribution to MSE, however, I do not think that it is fair to make jokes about me.

So my question: Is this kind of behavior accepted here?

Remark: my English is not so good, hence it is possible that I misunderstood something. If so, let me know.

Comment: No jokes about you.  Check out the url of the link.  See also the mathematics chat room transcript linked there.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, well now there will be jokes about me hahah.

Comment: While that chat comment was meant as a joke, of sorts, there is still an element of truth in it. Read it literally: *Just stopping by to say [this user](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current) is awesome. Great to have folks like this around.* I agree, every user is awesome (until proven otherwise), and there's nothing wrong with that. Don't feel bad, you got caught in the trap (like you were supposed to). But the truth is still there. Be the awesome person you are.

Comment: Sorry to have placed that "trap" there (even if only by copying somebody's trap); I'd have hoped the subsequent comments made the situation clear. Personally, I find the "joke" interesting. It is a bit of a personality-test, some users got upset, some were flattered (depending on reading it as ironic or litteraly).

Comment: There is no problem @quid, I discovered it was intendend to be joke, only after I post my question here.

Comment: I just fell for that joke.

Comment: Sometimes a well-placed compliment is the best kind of troll. (I had to think of GLaDOS: "Congratulations [INSERT NAME HERE]! You must be the pride of [INSERT HOMETOWN HERE].")

Comment: that kind of behavior is unacceptable. Understand this comment however you like ;)

Comment: Taking everybody for a short .. ride

Comment: This kind of " Behaviour " is accepted here :)

Comment: This is probably the funniest topic I have seen ever on the StackExchange sites. Thank you, @Tomás!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Cheer up! You're not the target of a rude joke in chat. Or, you're not the *only* target of a joke in chat.

The trick lies in the source of the original comment:

```
Just stopping by to say [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current) is awesome. Great to have folks like this around.
```

Note that it links to `https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current`, which is the profile of the *current user*: you! (Without "special powers" you can wean this by paying attention to where the link actually goes to before you click on it.) In your case it goes to [your profile](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42394/tom%c3%a1s). In my case it goes to [my profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8348/arthur-fischer). And in the case of the reader of this post, it goes to [their profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current).

So it seems that *everyone* was the target of this prank. Alternatively — taking [rolfl's interpretation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19132/what-is-the-point-in-banalize-someone-in-the-chat-room#comment69889_19132) — everyone is being flattered by perhaps our most polarising user; take *that* however you wish.

Comment: No comments =) ....

Comment: @Tomás: Well, there _is_ an upvoted answer... (Rest assured that you were not the only user to fall for this trick. Fundamental had his fun with it; time to let the cat out of the bag.)

Comment: Why do you have cats in bags? I'm calling PETA to report you!

Comment: Oh, I thought I was special, back to my hole...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Have you ever seen a cat in a bag? They absolutely love them!! Although not as much as boxes... (source: I have 4 cats)

Comment: @corsiKa: I know.

Answer (score 35):

I could not give credit at the time without spoiling the fun, but the idea wasn't mine. I rephrased a [chat message](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2793159#2793159) by *Mooseman is eating pizza*, which said

> [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) is the Hero of Stack Overflow.

Jokes aside, the `/users/current/` feature is useful for answering support questions. For example, if you want to tell someone to look at the reputation tab of their profile, [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) will work not only for them, but also for everyone else who looks up your answer later. It is

`https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation`

Comment: The evils (or joy) of HTTP cookies... the same link can return completely different content to different clients... as long as they have different cookies. Well... even without cookies you can return varying content based on different client IP addresses etc., which is info also available to the server; that's how http://whatismyipaddress.com/ and so forth work. The moral of this story is that you cannot always assume that anyone else sees the same content as you at a given URL. Usually it'll be the same content, but one should not assume that's always the case.